# Understanding Expected Value

Tags: probability

> If $X$ is a normally distributed random variable with standard deviation $\sigma=10$, and $P(X>16.34) = .1212$, what is the mean (expected value) of $X$?

**Attempt at solution:**
This problem doesn't make sense... standard deviation is given, by the probability $X>16.34$ has no upper bound, so how can this be computed? The expected value is just the summation of all the values which $=.1212$ here, so I'm not exactly sure what is being asked. please help!

Comment: "by the probability $X>16.34$ has no upper bound" uh... what?

Comment: The is no need to put an upper bound, but you may put upper bound M such that the P(X>M) will be so small such that it won't make any difference

Answer (score 1):

Hint:  For a normal distribution, the probability can be converted to how many standard deviations you are away from the mean.  For example, following [the 68-95-99.7 rule](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/68-95-99.7_rule) the chance that you are over $2\sigma$ above the mean is about $0.025$.  You should be able to find some $n$ such that the chance you are at least $n\sigma$ above the mean is $0.1212$.  This says that $\mu + n\sigma$ is that value.  If you have $n$ and $\sigma$, you can find $\mu$

Comment: Thanks for the push in the right direction, I will work through it from here.

Answer (score 1):

Let $\mu$ be the expected value of $X$. Normalizing gives,
$$
P\left(Z > \frac{16.34 - \mu}{10}\right) = .1212.
$$
Using a normal distribution chart, the corresponding $z$-score is approximately 1.17. Thus,
$$
\begin{align*}
1.17 &= \frac{16.34 - \mu}{10}\\
11.7 &= 16.34 - \mu\\
\mu &= 4.64
\end{align*}
$$

Comment: got it thanks!!!!

Answer (score 1):

The random variable $X$ has no *theoretical* upper bound; $X$ is indeed unbounded, mathematically speaking. However, the right tail of its distribution, being a normal curve, decays extremely fast -- the exponential of a negative quadratic. That means that for all intents and purposes, you should not be worrying about $X>\mu+10\sigma$, since the chances of this are astronomically low.

As for the problem at hand, if you convert to a standard normal variate
$$
Z=\frac{X-\mu}{\sigma}
$$
then
$$
0.1212=P(X > 16.34)=P\left(Z>\frac{16.34-\mu}{10}\right)
$$
is the area of a right tail of the normal distribution.
The corresponding cutoff value is $z\approx1.169$,
which leads us to
$$
X=\mu+\sigma Z\qquad\implies
$$
$$
\mu=X-\sigma Z=16.34-11.69=4.65\,.
$$

Comment: got it thanks!!!!!